# Redirect URLs without index.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

OK, what I need should fairly simply (and I've already noticed several other related questions, none of which works for me though).

I'm building a CodeIgniter-based website and I need to be able to access all controller using :

```
www.mysite.com/some-controller/some-method
```

instead of

```
www.mysite.com/index.php/some-controller/some-method
```

What should my **.htaccess** contain?

Comment: And you are really sure that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155333/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-2?rq=1) doesn't contain the answer you need?

Comment: Or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13714280/624466)

Comment: @eyecatchUp After updating the paths in `RewriteCond` (since the CI installation resides in a SUB-folder), the answer in your link **does work**. However, how could I make it so that the `/index.php/something` URLs do not work any more? (I just need their without-index.php counterparts).

Comment: Give a try to this link. it might help u
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155333/remove-index-php-from-url-codeigniter-2]

Comment: @Sid syntax  [name]( link to name without spaces)

Comment: -1 for obvious reason....

Comment: Same question was already been asked few times before

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon To force redirects from `/index.php/controller/method` to `/controller/method` take a look at the update on [this post](http://www.geedew.com/2011/04/05/remove-index-php-codeigniter/). For me, it worked well using [this .htaccess](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tqvMkkG0)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one
Remove

```
 $config['index_page'] ='index.php';
```

and replace with

```
 $config['index_page'] ='';
```

Comment: My `index_page` was already set to *nothing* but it still didn't work...

Answer (score 1):

Please put this to your .htaccess file

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
  </IfModule>
```

Comment: Please don't post duplicated answers, but rather link to existing threads (see comments to the question).

Comment: OK...will tak care of that. But this one is the one that I have been using for my various CI based projects.

Comment: Hmm... Thanks for the reply. However, weirdly enough it does not work for me. (and I've changed the `RewriteRule` to `the-full-path/to-my-website-subfolder/index.php?/$1` - not sure If that was the right thing to do though....)