# Activating .htaccess in my CodeIgniter project (Removing "index.php")

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter

I am trying to remove the index.php segment from my project, but I can't. I tested several articles quoted here in StackOverflow, but still unable to.

This is my project structure:

```
(In /var/www/project directory)
project
--assets
--system
--.htaccess
--index.php
--info.php
--quickmenu.php

PHP version: 5.3.10
SO: Ubuntu 12.04
Apache version: 2.2.22
CodeIgniter: 2.1.3
```

My config.php file:

```
$config['base_url'] = "HTTP://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/project/";

$config['index_page'] = "";

$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";


$config['url_suffix'] = "";


$config['language'] = "portugues";

$config['charset'] = "iso-8859-1";


$config['enable_hooks'] = FALSE;


$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';



$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-';


$config['enable_query_strings'] = FALSE;
$config['directory_trigger'] = 'd';  // experimental not currently in use
$config['controller_trigger'] = 'c';
$config['function_trigger'] = 'm';

$config['log_threshold'] = '1';


$config['log_path'] = '';

$config['log_date_format'] = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';


$config['cache_path'] = '/var/ci/cache/';


$config['encryption_key'] = "q7uP3mprMYuFFvbNcXyC6uPXs2ZUezxh";


$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']          = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']            = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent']         = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']      = 300;
$config['sess_storage']                 = 'database';

$config['sess_database']                = 'default';
$config['sess_timeout']                 = 7200;
$config['sess_destroy_on_timeout']      = FALSE;
$config['sess_update_interval']         = 180;
$config['sess_gc_probability']          = 10;
$config['sess_http_only']               = FALSE;
$config['sess_secure']                  = FALSE;
$config['sess_forwarded_ip']            = FALSE;


$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";

$config['global_xss_filtering'] = FALSE;

$config['compress_output'] = FALSE;


$config['time_reference'] = 'local';


$config['rewrite_short_tags'] = FALSE;

/* End of file config.php */
/* Location: ./system/application/config/config.php */
```

My .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /project/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]


    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Complement:

With the url doesn't work:

```
http://localhost/project/#../directory/controller/method
```

With these urls works:

```
http://localhost/project/#index.php/directory/controller/method
http://localhost/project/index.php/#directory/controller/method
```

Comment: Hope this helps :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13714057/codeigniter-remove-index-php-with-htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.

Was missing install the mod_rewrite package on my PHP. So after this just config the config/config.php and .htaccess files.

Below the article who I used for install mod_rewrite module for PHP in my UBUNT:

[How to enable mod_rewrite for Apache 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/869092/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-for-apache-2-2)

Thanks everyone for advice, if not for them I would not have tried this workaround.

Answer (score 3):

Try with changing uri_protocol from AUTO to REQUEST_URI

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = "REQUEST_URI";
```

You can refer this link : http://taggedzi.com/articles/display/codeigniter-2-htaccess-and-friendly-urls

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but doesn't work. I tried with all the options for 'uri_protocol', but nevertheless doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are uploading on the server, then Remove RewriteBase /project/

and write  RewriteBase /

I was doing the same mistake. I just tested and it worked.

Comment: Try putting
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';

Answer (score 1):

Change your `config.php` as:

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php";

$config['uri_protocol'] = "ORIG_PATH_INFO";
```

Then place this rule in your `/project/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /project/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

**Also make sure there is no `.htaccess` present in `/project/directory/`**.

Comment: Are you trying to work: `http://localhost/project/#../directory/controller/method`?

Comment: Anything after `#` isn't even received by web server.

Comment: If I insert the "index.php" after # works. This Exemple works: http://localhost/project/#index.php/directory/controller/method

Comment: There might be some Javascript snippet passing string after `#` to web server.

Comment: Yes, I have a Ajax Jquery for to load the controller.

Comment: ok so looks like you need change in your jquery code not on server side.

Comment: I have just removed the jquery-ajax-request code, but the problem persists. The controller are loaded but with the "index.php" segment.

Comment: By change I have to enable something in apache for the .htaccess to work?

Comment: So you're trying `http://localhost/project/directory/controller/method` now instead of `http://localhost/project/index.php/directory/controller/method`?

Comment: Yes, without the index.php segment.

Comment: Ok try my updated answer. (Sorry I am no CI expert so its a mix-match between CI and mod_rewrite).

Comment: Still doesn't work, but thank you so so much anubhava for help-me.

Comment: Hmm I had tested this before posting. Which URL didn't work for you?

Comment: I have just posted the solution. Was missing the mod_rewrite on my PHP.

Comment: Yes `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]` will work with `$config['uri_protocol'] = "AUTO";` itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found the exact solution for mine.You can try it.
I assume that the most important is  RewriteBase /
and ./CI/ will be your application contained folder name. Example: CI/application
So be careful.

```
       RewriteEngine On
       RewriteBase /
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
       RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./CI/index.php/$1 [L]
```

But if you are svn server then use:
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php/$1 [L]

These will work if you are putting with/without index.php 
     here`ex: http://kabircse.tk/CI/
     or  http://kabircse.tk/CI/index.php

Both will find out your route controller. If your route controller is mc then it will find     it as http://kabircse.tk/CI/mc